# Crash at _CFAutoreleasePoolPop

Tags: ios, block, release, nsautoreleasepool, runloop

I got a crash from `Fabric`,the stack is below:

```html
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                6806634868 objc_release + 20
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         6813456656 _Block_release + 256
2  libobjc.A.dylib                6806640420 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 564
3  CoreFoundation                 6529519172 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
4  UIKit                          6605817924 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 76
5  CoreFoundation                 6530394704 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
6  CoreFoundation                 6530382300 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
7  CoreFoundation                 6530383292 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
8  CoreFoundation                 6529519780 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
9  GraphicsServices               6682260900 GSEventRunModal + 168
10 UIKit                          6606283712 UIApplicationMain + 1488
11 Spec                           4297532060 main (main.m:15)
12 libdyld.dylib                  6813280776 start + 4
```

I don't know why it would be `_Block_release` after `(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)`. Is it possible that a block was added to autoreleasepool?if possible, why the block crashed at release and it not crashed at invoke?

Comment: Try to debug using zombies

Comment: @newacct We didn't know when and why this bug would happen.So I can't  debug it with Xcode by using zombies.

Answer (score 1):

Ok，I had resolve this bug.The reason for the crash was that I had hook the function `objectAtIndex` for NSMutableArray.And If user switch from background,the app would get a crash `-[UIKeyboardLayoutStar release]: message sent to deallocated`.

So remove the hook code will resolve this bug.

Comment: you can have another solution. Set your file where you hook the `NSMutableArray` method compiler flags is `-fno-objc-arc`. Then rebuild your project. You can confirm the question.